# The difference between the block and function scopes in C

Tags: c, namespaces, stack, scope

What is the difference between the block and function scopes in C99 in terms of what happens on stack when a function / block is entered and left?

Comment: "Block" is more general that "function". There's no "stack" in C99.

Comment: Function: `PUSH`, `POP`. Block: nothing.

Comment: @KerrekSB I think OP is looking for an implementation detail.

Comment: @KerrekSB There is no call-stack in C99?Please elaborate.

Comment: @H2CO3 You mean to say a call-stack is created for a function, while no such thing is done for a block, right?

Comment: @SheerFish The word "stack" does not appear anywhere in the text of C99.  (I am not exaggerating.  I searched the PDF.)  A conforming implementation is required to support recursive function calls and to create new instances of all variables with "automatic storage duration" every time their containing block is entered recursively.  (§6.5.2.2p11, §6.2.4p5 respectively)  The most common way to implement these requirements is with a stack, but there are other ways to do it.

Comment: Indeed, the question was whether it's a common practice that a call stack is generated for a block or not.

Comment: @Zack Is the material in such PDFs `densely` packed?Can a person with average understanding of C read that document or it's better left to professional programmers or those who are very good in C?

Comment: @Witiko Assuming a typical stack-based implementation, the answer to that question is "no".  Furthermore, even in the unusual cases where the compiler might change the stack pointer within a nested block (e.g. this might make sense if a large or dynamically-sized variable is declared within a nested block) it would not generate a new *call frame*, because no function call has occurred.

Comment: @Zack That sounds quite credible.

Comment: @SheerFish I am perhaps not the person to ask, since I used to *implement* C for a living, but I would think that someone with an average understanding of C could learn something by reading that document.  As standards documents go, it's far from the least-readable I've ever seen.  The only caution to readers I'd give is that it uses lots and lots of terms with precise definitions that don't quite match their intuitive meaning, so you need to read it from the beginning so you know all the definitions.

Comment: @SheerFish Why don't you have a look: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, a compiler *could* generate code to allocate a stack frame on entry to any block that contains local variables. In such a case, there wouldn't be much difference at all.

In practice, most compilers compute the maximum size of local variables that could be used by any path through a function, then allocate that size of stack frame on entry. Variables in any block inside the function are simply different offsets from the stack pointer. Note that in such a case, two (or more) blocks may use the same addresses. For example, with source code like this:

```
void f(int x) { 
    if (x) {
        long y;
    }
    else { 
        float z;
    }
}
```

...chances are quite good that `y` and `z` will end up at the same address.

Comment: In general, it is impossible for a compiler to compute the maximum size of local objects in advance, due to variable-length arrays. E.g., in `{ foo(); { int bar[baz()]; } }`, the stack allocation needed for `bar` cannot be known when `foo` is called, let alone at compile time.

Comment: Could the compiler in such a case treat the block as a function and create a new stack frame for the block upon entry?

Comment: @Witiko It could theoretically do that but I'm not aware of any compiler that actually does it that way; full stack frames are normally reserved for actual, y'know, function calls.  The typical implementation involves enlarging the existing stack frame when control reaches the VLA declaration. But again, it doesn't *have* to do it that way. I don't know any compiler that does *this* either, but another plausible implementation technique is to emit calls to `malloc` and `free` at appropriate points!

Answer (score 2):

The only thing an implementation is required to do when control enters either a function or a block scope is to *behave as if* new instances have been created of all data objects directly in that scope with "automatic storage duration." *Behave as if* means it can do something different as long as the program being compiled can't tell the difference (or could only tell the difference by doing something whose behavior is undefined).  For instance, if a variable is *declared* at function scope but only used within one subblock, the compiler can collapse its live range to that subblock, and probably will, because this makes register allocation easier.

An implementation is not required to do *anything* when control exits a function or block scope.  The lifetimes of all automatic-storage-duration objects directly in that scope end, but no program can tell that this has happened without triggering undefined behavior.

There is no requirement for a C implementation to have a stack, and a stack is not the only way to implement the above requirements. See for instance "[Cheney on the M.T.A.](http://www.pipeline.com/~hbaker1/CheneyMTA.html)" and [c2:SpaghettiStack](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SpaghettiStack).

C implementations that *do* have a stack will normally try to avoid adjusting the stack pointer in the middle of a function, for reasons too complicated to go into here.  This can mean that a value with block scope survives on the stack longer than its declared lifetime, but it's still undefined behavior to access it.  The compiler is allowed to recycle storage for values that are no longer in scope, but it is *also* allowed to recycle storage for values that are still in scope but will not be accessed anymore ("dead" in compiler jargon).  Historically compilers have been much more aggressive about doing that for values in registers than for values in stack slots, but again, that's a distinction that doesn't necessarily *exist* on your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
void foo(int n)            // <-- beginning of function scope
{                          // <-- beginning of function body scope
    int x = n;

    for (;;)
    {                      // <-- beginning of block scope
       int q = n;
       x *= q;
    }                      // <-- end of block scope

    foo(x);

    {                      // <-- another block scope
        int w = x;
    }

}                          // <-- end of function body scope
                           //     and of function scope
```

Nothing "happens" when a scope ends, but a variable only lives inside the scope where it is declared (with some arcane exceptions). It is up to the implementation to reuse the space of variables of previous, nested scopes that have ended.

Comment: This might actually be a good time to use K&R parameter declarations, in order to make the difference between function scope and function-body scope more obvious.

Comment: nice answer of the mention that the function scope starts with the parameters. But no, a variable (that is not a VLA) "lives" as long as its declaration scope can be entered by the flow of execution, e.g through a `goto` or `longjmp`. But probably you meant that with "arcane exceptions".

Comment: @JensGustedt: Yeah, and also compound statements are a bit weird, I think... feel free to edit if you think it can be made clearer :-)